# Search Bar Loses FirstResponder when rotated from Portrait to Landscape mode

Tags: ios, uilabel, uisplitviewcontroller, autolayout

I'm trying to mimic the iPad Mail app. In portrait mode, when the popover's searchbar has first responder and I rotate to landscape, the popover's searchbar loses first responder. I want to continue giving the search bar first responder in landscape mode when it has first responder in portrait mode. How can I do this?

Portrait mode:
http://postimg.org/image/kwjs9xkcx/

After Rotation:
http://postimg.org/image/al7fh9snl/
Notice that the searchbar resigns first responder.

Thanks!

Comment: This is what I actually want (Search Bar having first responder):
http://postimg.org/image/5cgzx4zm9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the method that deals with roation of the view

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
```

check to see what interface you are in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
         [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

hope that helps!